# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2' has no attribute '_BaseFeaturesLayer'

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

So I am new to machine learning, I was trying to follow this guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started#using_tensorboard_with_keras_modelfit

I was trying to add this line to my model:

```
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]
```

It works but when I try to run the tensorboard it will fail:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2' has no attribute '_BaseFeaturesLayer'

I am running python version 3.8.2 and TF version 2.5.0

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Comment: Please provide more relevant code or at least some reproducible code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this happened because I had a problem with mixing tensorflow versions,got fixed by uninstalling and installing it again